# Plugins not getting updates

Tags: plugins

i installed many Ubuntu on my PC and i couldn't even listen to a single music file or watch even a small video, it always says plugins not installed. If it can't even those small plugins then whast is the purpose of that whole DVD of Ubuntu...?? And what is the difference between CD and DVD of Ubuntu if it can't even install any plugin from the ??

Comment: This sounds like more of a rant then a question. Do you really want an answer? I would suggest editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, be warned that it might not be legal in some countries, because of software patents.

With that being said, here is how to install it, click here:

[ubuntu-restricted-extras](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntu-restricted-extras)

Or
you can open up a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Select yes, and you'll have ubuntu-restricted-extras installed and working

Comment: i tried "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras" way, but its saying unable to locate packages "Ubuntu-restricted-extras" wht do i do now??

Comment: firstly try doing `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: if this work tick this as wright answer a tick below answer